# How do I move the website title above the banner image

Tags: html, wordpress

My website banner has suddenly appeared above my header text, rather than below it. I've fixed the CSS on the desktop version but I can't get it right on the phone. 
(It's wordpress and the text is added as a banner title and tagline)

Can someone please tell me what the code should be.

The website is www.flowersforeveryone.co.za

```
@media (max-width: 475px){
    .page-banner-wrap .page-banner .page-header > .page-title{
        font-size: 14pt;
        line-height: 1.2;
}

#lsx-banner .tagline{
font-size: 9pt;

}

.page-banner-wrap .page-banner > .page-banner-image{
    height: 30vh;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the CSS below should solve the problem. I don't know why this happened. I assume the DOM markup changed and so the banner is not displaying correctly anymore. You might need to tweak the settings below. This is just a hint where to start. I made the banner quite appealing but there is still room for improvement. I repositioned the background (changed the size at smaller screen devices - 720px / 768px breakpoint) plus stretched the image container at specific screen sizes (<= 991px) to 100%.

```
.page-banner-wrap .page-banner > .container {
    margin-top: 20px;
}  

.page-banner-wrap .page-banner > .page-banner-image {
    background-position: 50% 65% !important;
}    

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)
.page-banner-wrap .page-banner > .page-banner-image {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 768px)
.page-banner-wrap .page-banner > .page-banner-image {
    background-size: 350px;
}

@media (max-width: 720px)
.page-id-10 .page-banner-wrap .page-banner > .page-banner-image {
    background-size: 300px;
}
```

Edit: Changing the container margin to top might also be a good idea to get a more appealing look on desktop.

Comment: Cool.. thanks! I added this to the bottom of my custom CSS script but now for the mobile the banner image doesn't appear at all....

Comment: @Michelle I added `position: absolute;` now it should work at least for me it does

Comment: Do you know what's the best way to clean my css code? I may have code elsewhere that may also refer to these same elements that may overwrite things? (I don't understand it enough to mess with it)

Comment: @Michelle It's not easy to manually check for possible overrides. But AFAIK there are browser plugins and websites that test your website for obsolet CSS. But be aware that this might be limited per page basis. So CSS that might be used on page A might not be used on page B. So you have to be careful. I have no good recommendation. But it might be useful to open another thread on that topic.

Comment: @Michelle If the overrides comprehend a lot of rules it might be worth checking for unused stuff. If there are just a handful of rules it might not be worth at all. But generally every bit saved on transmission is a good one ;). But I wouldn't mess to much except there is room for potential optimization. Optimizing images, minimizing resources often saves more that a few CSS rules.